# Autosar library CalculateCRC16bitARC

Tags: c, autosar

I am making my own implementation of the autosar CRC library and I have problems calculating the 16-bit crc function with reflected bits. I have read the documentation and some forums and I still cannot find the fault in my program.

I am basing myself on the following table from the official documentation:

Data bytes (0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)       CRC result = 0000

Data bytes (0xF2, 0x01, 0x83)            CRC result = C2E1

Data bytes (0x0F, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x55)       CRC result = 0BE3

I don't get the expected results.

```
uint32 Reflect(uint32 data, uint8 bit_count)
{
    uint32 reflection = 0;
    for (uint8 bit = 0; bit < bit_count; bit++) 
    {
        if (data & 0x01) 
        {
            reflection |= (1 << ((bit_count - 1) - bit));
        }
        data >>= 1;
    }
    return reflection;
}





uint16 Crc_CalculateCRC16ARC(const uint8* Crc_DataPtr, uint32 Crc_Length, uint16 Crc_StartValue16, boolean Crc_IsFirstCall)
{
    const uint16 Crc_Polynomial = 0x8005; 
    uint16 crcValue = Crc_StartValue16;

    if(Crc_IsFirstCall)
    {
        crcValue = 0xFFFF;
    }

    for (int i = (int)Crc_Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        crcValue ^= Reflect(Crc_DataPtr[i], 8) << 8;

        for (uint8 bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)
        {
            if (crcValue & 0x8000) 
            {
                crcValue = (crcValue << 1) ^ Crc_Polynomial;
            }
            else
            {
                crcValue <<= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return Reflect(crcValue ^ 0xFFFF, 16);
}
```

Comment: You provided code: Good!  Please clarify exactly "what's wrong".  If possible, please give example input(s), the "good result", and the "bad" result.  Along with any other details that will help us answer your question.

Comment: `1 <<` is pretty much always a bug in C. It should be `1u <<` or your code will invoke undefined behavior for `1 << 31`.

Comment: Also you should neither be using naive `int` nor home-brewed non-standard types. Use the types from `stdint.h`. Good engineering = follow technical standards, bad engineering = ignoring standards or making private non-standards.

Comment: @Lundin, he is using the AUTOSAR defined types. They are not home-brewed.

Comment: @kesselhaus Yes they are. Poorly designed sub-standards who can't bother to harmonize themselves with already established standards are to be considered as "local garage standards".

Comment: @paulsm4 I have already given the example